# Javascript generated table sorting

Tags: javascript, sorttable.js

I wrote a JS code that generates a table and plugs it into a div on my page. I would like to use the sort table plugin from [here](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/).
here is the code I have until now:

```
  TableHtml = ''
  TableHtml += '<div id="table_wrapper" class="scrollable"><table style="width:900px" id="mytable" class="sortable tabular">'
  TableHtml += '<thead><tr>'
  TableHtml += '<th class="labels"><span class="nowrap">Date</span></th>'
  TableHtml += '<th class="labels"><span class="nowrap">Client</span></th>'
  TableHtml += '<th class="labels"><span class="nowrap">Pass</span></th>'
  TableHtml += '<th class="labels"><span class="nowrap">Objet</span></th>'
  TableHtml += '<th class="labels"><span class="nowrap">Panne</span></th>'
  TableHtml += '<th class="labels"><span class="nowrap">Cause</span></th>'
  TableHtml += '<th><div id="headerbg"><span class="nowrap">Action</span></div></th>'
  TableHtml += '<TH class="sorttable_nosort scrollbarCol"></TH>'
  TableHtml += '</tr></thead><tbody>'

  var trclass = '';
  var d=0               
  if(!rsDetail.bof) {
    rsDetail.MoveFirst()
    while(!rsDetail.eof) {
      detAvis  = rsDetail.fields(0).value;
      detDate = rsDetail.fields(2).value;
      detClient = rsDetail.fields(4).value
      detPass = rsDetail.fields(5).value
      detObjet = rsDetail.fields(9).value
      detPanne = rsDetail.fields(10).value
      detCause = rsDetail.fields(11).value
      detAction = rsDetail.fields(12).value

        //filling up he rows
      if (d%2){
      trclass='d1'
      }
      else{
      trclass='d2'
      }
      TableHtml += '<tr id="' + detAvis + '" class="' + trclass + '" onclick="Select(' + detAvis + '); showDetails(' + detAvis + ');">'
      TableHtml += '<td class="td1">' + detDate + '</td>'
      TableHtml += '<td class="td2">' + detClient + '</td>'
      TableHtml += '<td class="td3">' + detPass + '</td>'
      TableHtml += '<td class="td4">' + detObjet + '</td>'
      TableHtml += '<td class="td5">' + detPanne + '</td>'
      TableHtml += '<td class="td6">' + detCause + '</td>'
      TableHtml += '<td class="td7">' + detAction + '</td>'
      TableHtml += '</tr>'        
      d++
      rsDetail.MoveNext()
    }
  }   
  TableHtml += '</tbody></table></div>'

  rsDetail.close()
  document.getElementById('DetailTable').innerHTML = TableHtml;
```

and my reference in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/sorttable.js"></script>
```

the reference is from [here](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js).

The table is scrollabale but somehow stays unsortable. Any idea what the problem might be? 
I have tried attributing the `sortable` class to another table that is not JS generated on the same page and it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call the makeSortable:

```
sorttable.makeSortable(document.getElementById('mytable'));
```

see the comment here form scott W (search for makeSortable):
http://www.kryogenix.org/days/2007/04/07/sorttable-v2-making-your-tables-even-more-sortable

and here also mentions makeSortable:
http://www.kryogenix.org/bugs/sorttable/ajax-tables.html

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the sorttable.js is linked/executed before you table is inserted.
you can try loading the js file on document ready or using jquery.

Comment: You mean loading the sottable.js file on document ready? How do I do that?